# How can I iterate through nested HashMaps in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin, and I am having trouble finding an idiomatic way to translate the snippet of Python below into Kotlin.
Let's say that I have a list of words that I am trying to insert into a Trie data structure, represented as nested dictionaries in Python. Terminal nodes in the Trie will be marked simply by adding the key `#` to that level of the dictionary.

```
trie = {}
for word in words:
    cur = trie
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in cur:
            cur[letter] = {}
        cur = cur[letter]
    cur['#'] = {}
```

For the input words:
`["test","this","trie"]`
you would get the following representation:

```
{'t': {'e': {'s': {'t': {'#': {}}}}, 'h': {'i': {'s': {'#': {}}}}, 'r': {'i': {'e': {'#': {}}}}}}
```

I have tried the following, in Kotlin:

```
val trie: MutableMap<Char, MutableMap<Char, Any>> = mutableMapOf()
for (word in words) {
    var cur = trie
    for (letter in word) {
        if (!cur.containsKey(letter)) {
            cur[letter] = mutableMapOf()
        }
        cur = cur[letter]
    }
    cur['#'] = mutableMapOf()
}
```

However, this gets me the following compilation error:

```
error: type mismatch: inferred type is MutableMap<Char, Any>? but MutableMap<Char, MutableMap<Char, Any>> was expected
        cur = cur[letter]
```

I am aware that I could explicitly create Node objects which contain a HashMap pointing to other Nodes to represent the Trie, however I am interested in understanding if there would be a way to represent the Trie as a HashMap of HashMaps in Kotlin as I did above in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, at the cost of all type safety.

Just to emphasize, what you've already pointed out in your question is the correct approach. You should absolutely make a `Node` dataclass that contains a hashmap pointing to the additional nodes. This is the correct recursive data structure for this job. **What follows is the wrong way to solve this problem.**

But you asked for an infinitely nested hashmap. We can always store whatever data we want into a `HashMap` if the value type is `Any`.

```
val trie: MutableMap<Char, Any> = mutableMapOf()
```

Now Kotlin doesn't have nearly enough type information to figure out what our inner maps look like, so we have to add annotations to those.

```
cur[letter] = mutableMapOf<Char, Any>()
```

and

```
cur['#'] = mutableMapOf<Char, Any>()
```

Finally, when we "zoom in" on a nested map, we'll get an `Any`. We're just going to quietly [cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html) that to `MutableMap<Char, Any>`, and nobody will notice.

```
cur = cur[letter] as MutableMap<Char, Any>
```

Complete example:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val words = listOf("test", "this", "trie")
  val trie: MutableMap<Char, Any> = mutableMapOf()
  for (word in words) {
    var cur = trie
    for (letter in word) {
      if (!cur.containsKey(letter)) {
        cur[letter] = mutableMapOf<Char, Any>()
      }
      cur = cur[letter] as MutableMap<Char, Any>
    }
    cur['#'] = mutableMapOf<Char, Any>()
  }
  println(trie)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible interpretation of Silvio's answer as a type safe version:

```
val words = listOf("test", "this", "trie")

data class Node(
  var char: Char? = null,
  val children: MutableMap<Char, Node> = mutableMapOf()
) {
  override fun toString(): String = children.onEach { it.toString() }.toString()
}

val root = Node()

words.forEach { word ->
  var currentNode = root
  word.forEach { char ->
    if (!currentNode.children.contains(char)) {
      currentNode.children[char] = Node(char)
    }
    currentNode = currentNode.children[char]!!
  }
  currentNode.children['#'] = Node()
}

println(root)

// Output: {t={e={s={t={#={}}}}, h={i={s={#={}}}}, r={i={e={#={}}}}}}
```